# Entities storage for mocks

Tags: c#, .net, testing, mocking

We would like to mock some services (usually, external) in our application. Mocks implemention should rely on data entities that should be easily editable in XML.

For example, mocking trivial method *GetUsers*:

```
class UserServiceMock : IUserService
{
    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return MockRepository.Get<User>();
    }
}
```

And users list should be editable in *Users.xml*:

```
<Users>
    <User id="1" name="TestUser" />
</Users>
```

Entities can be complex classes of course. It should be easy to add and configure new entities.

What's the best approach to implement such mocks?

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing, I wouldn't rely on user-editable files to provide mock data.  Instead, use Rhino.Mocks to mock out your IUserService and return data you need for **unit** testing.

```
var userService = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUserService>();
userService.Stub(s => s.GetUsers()).Returns(new [] {
    new User { id = 1, name = "TestUser" }
    };
```

I usually use seed data (like "users.xml") for integration/stress testing.

Comment: I'm talking about manual testing, not unit tests, but thanks for your answer.